# Как открыть сайт в WebView JavaFX, запрашивающий *.pfx сертификат?

Tags: java, javafx

Использую javafx.scene.web.WebView. Другие адреса грузятся, этот нет, выдает пустое окно. Когда гружу в браузере Google Chrome, вылетает окошко с запросом сертификата, которое я подтверждаю и только после этого грузится сайт. Сертификат добавлен на пк с помощью файлика *.pfx . Как сделать чтобы грузился нужный мне адрес через WebView javafx?

```
webEngine.load("https://www.**********.ru/");
```

**upd**
свойства сертификата в хроме:

[image: в браузере]

Answer (score 1):

JDK 8 использует по умолчанию [TLS 1.2](https://blogs.oracle.com/java-platform-group/entry/java_8_will_use_tls). Попробуйте использовать первую версию:

```
-Djdk.tls.client.protocols="TLSv1"
```

Еще есть такое решение:

```
TrustManager[] trustAllCerts = new TrustManager[] { 
    new X509TrustManager() {     
        public java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() { 
            return null;
        } 
        public void checkClientTrusted( 
            java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] certs, String authType) {
            } 
        public void checkServerTrusted( 
            java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] certs, String authType) {
        }
    } 
}; 

try {
    SSLContext sc = SSLContext.getInstance("SSL"); 
    sc.init(null, trustAllCerts, new java.security.SecureRandom()); 
    HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultSSLSocketFactory(sc.getSocketFactory());
} catch (GeneralSecurityException e) {
} 

try { 
    URL url = new URL("https://hostname/index.html"); 
} catch (MalformedURLException e) {
} 

webEngine.load("https://example.com");
```

Comment: в браузере пишет, что сертификат использует TLS 1.2, но попробую. второй способ не помог. я думаю все же надо прямо указать на сертификат, только как я не знаю

Comment: @НиколайКонорев http://superuser.com/questions/747377/enable-tls-1-1-and-1-2-for-clients-on-java-7